# How add libraries to my .jar file

Tags: java, opencv, jar

I have a project on Netbeans working okay with opencv library.

I have set on project Properties > Run: `-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64"`

If I run the project on NetBeans it works.

However, when I build the JAR file and try to `java -Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64" -jar myjar.jar` from cmd, it throws

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Mat

What am I missing to build my jar?

**Edit**

In the directory where .jar has been built, I create a dir called `lib` and inside I put opencv-300.jar: If I execute `java -cp "lib/opencv-330.jar;myjar.jar" gui.Client` it works...
Is there any way to execute the app without running that command?

Comment: You need to create executable jar.

Comment: what do you mean by "executable" jar? I already have my .jar

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_(file_format)#Executable_JAR_files

Comment: @tsolakp They have an executable jar, which is launching.  The opencv library class is not being found.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a Native library file (.dll/Windows or .so/Linux) with two ways:

1) Load the file by providing the full path:

```
System.load("my/full/path/opencv.dll");
```

2) If your native file is located inside your Java Library Path:

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv");
```

Take notice that in the second case you only need to provide the name of your native file (without its extension).

The default Java Library Path depends on OS:

*On Windows, it maps to PATH

On Linux, it maps to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

On OS X, it maps to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH*

If you want to set your own Java Library Path:

```
try {
        System.setProperty("java.library.path","YOUR/PATH");
        Field fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
        fieldSysPath.setAccessible(true);
        fieldSysPath.set(null, null);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Failed to set Java Library Path: " + ex.getMessage);
    }
```

Comment: I think I am loading the DLL correctly (I have already done what you said), however the problem comes when opencv-300.jar is not being linked or something like that. - for using opencv on java you need to use the opencv.dll and opencv.jar

Comment: Are you using Gradle?

Comment: How are you creating the Jar? jars/libs should be included in this jar

Comment: see last edit, I could run it but using `java -cp ...`, is there another way to run my jar correctly without using that command?